# The "If" function works wrong in apply

Tags: r

```
test<-matrix(1:9,3,3)
test
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I would like to calculate the sum of each column, especially when the value is greater than 2.
The results I wanted were

```
    3    15    24
```

I used the following code:

```
    apply(test,2,function(x){
    if (x>2){
            sum<-sum(x)
    }
    return(sum)
}
)
```

it turns out like this:

```
[[1]]
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")

[[2]]
[1] 15

[[3]]
[1] 24
```

why is that?

Comment: You should pay attention to the warning messages that get printed. `if()` tests a single condition, so you are testing only if the first element in the column is greater than 2. Since `sum` is the name of a function, in the first column the first row is 1, so `x>2` is false, so you never define `sum` as a value, so when you `return(sum)` you are returning the function.

Comment: Perhaps you want `colSums(test * (test > 2))`?

Comment: What about counting how many numbers in each column were greater than 2 ? The results may be 1,3,3. I do not how to use "length" in this way.

Comment: Well, that's a different question (more or less). Counting how many in each column greater than 2 is (the easy way) `colSums(test > 2)` or (the hard way with `sum`) `apply(test, 2, function(x) sum(x > 2))` or (the harder way with `length`) `apply(test, 2, function(x) length(x[x > 2]))`.

Comment: A piece of advice for next time - I did not downvote your question; I appreciate that it is reproducible - but I have two guesses as to why others did downvote: (1) you ignored warnings and didn't mention them in the question. (2) when you say "the if function works wrong in apply" it makes it sound like you're doing everything right but there's a bug in R. If instead you say "How do I use the if function in apply?" you acknowledge that your code is the problem and you need help fixing it. It's a subtle difference but it usually gets a much friendlier response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your code, I get lots of warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x > 2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The warnings are there to help, don't ignore them!

Your first column is the vector `x = 1:3`. If you run `if(x > 2)` on that, it returns `FALSE` because `if()` is only made to evaluate a single condition, so it only tests the first element, `1`. It also gives a warning like above to let you know something is possibly wrong. With the `if()` not being triggered, your next line of code to run is `return(sum)` - and at this point the only `sum` object that R knows about is the function `sum`, so this is returned, hence your output:

```
[[1]]
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

I think what you meant to write is:

```
apply(test, 2, function(x){
    sum(x[x > 2])
  }
)
# [1]  3 15 24
```

This will sum the values of `x` that are greater than 2. And you can test it on `x = 1:3` or `x = 4:6` to be sure.

```
x = 1:3
sum(x[x > 2])
# [1] 3
x = 4:6
sum(x[x > 2])
# [1] 15
```

We can also take a shortcut in this case. `test > 2` will give `TRUE` or `FALSE` - which is equivalent to 1 or 0 - depending on the values.

```
test > 2
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] FALSE TRUE TRUE
# [2,] FALSE TRUE TRUE
# [3,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

If we multiply this (element-wise) with `test`, the false values will zero out the values less than 2

```
test * (test > 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    4    7
# [2,]    0    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
```

And on this we can use the convenient `colSums` function

```
colSums(test * (test > 2))
# [1]  3 15 24
```

Comment: That's great. Then I can understand why colSums(test > 2) 
works in the way I wanted. Thank you so much. I learned a lot in your way of thinking.

Comment: Ming: Please be a responsible SO user and accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry, Mike Wise. I just got to know that I was responsible to accept the accept the answer. Now I have accepted it. Thanks for your remind.